# VBA MS Project Save Multiple Custom Reports as PDFs to Location

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to figure the VBA to save 7 separate custom reports made within MS Project as PDFs to a particular folder on a drive.

For example I would like to save the report named "Lauren" as a PDF to X:\Schedule\Schedules , then also save report named "Carol" as a PDF to the same location, then Report "Jenni" to the same location, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can change both the report name and the exported PDF location\name by hand or with string manipulation.

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro Macro2
' Macro Recorded 11/3/17 by me.
    ApplyReport Name:="Lauren"
    DocumentExport fileName:="X:\Schedule\Schedules\Lauren.pdf"
End Sub
```